# property signin, sign up does not exist on type AuthService

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt, nestjs-gateways

auth.controller file

```
`import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';

describe('AuthController', () => {
  let controller: AuthController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AuthController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});`
```

auth.service file

```
`import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({})
export class AuthService {
signin()
{
    return { msg: 'i am signin' };
}

signup()
{
    return  { msg: 'i am signup' };
}

}`
```

i am beginner level and getting this type of error even if remove all the code to simple return message my vcode gives same error what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're not getting a Dependency Injection error related to a missing `AuthService` dependency. You need to provide a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#custom-providers) for the `AuthService` to inject into the `AuthController` for the purpose of testing.

[This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a lot of testing examples to take a look at